# React Hook useCallback received a function whose dependencies are unknown. Pass an inline function instead. useMemo doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How can i fix this? I see question like this where people said that useMemo can help. But this is not about like that situation and useMemo fix doesn't work and create just more bugs.

```
export const Search: React.FC = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<string>('');
  const inputRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const onClickClear = () => {
    dispatch(setSearchValue(''));
    setValue('');
    inputRef.current?.focus();
  };

  const updateSearchValue = React.useCallback(
    debounce((str: string) => {
      dispatch(setSearchValue(str));
    }, 150),
    [],
  );

  const onChangeInput = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
    updateSearchValue(event.target.value);
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this instead?  `useCallback` takes two params.. an inline function, and a dependency array.

```
const updateSearchValue = React.useCallback((str: string) => {
  debounce(() => {
    dispatch(setSearchValue(str));
  }, 150);
}, [dispatch]);

const onChangeInput = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
    updateSearchValue(event.target.value); 
  };
```

Comment: This cause error like this: 

React Hook React.useCallback has unnecessary dependencies: 'debounce' and 'setSearchValue'. Either exclude them or remove the dependency array. Outer scope values like 'debounce' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component.

Comment: have you tried removing those two from the dependency array?  the errors can be pretty helpful.  I'm working a bit blindly without seeing the rest of your code

Comment: Yes i Tried to do this. This give us nothing change :(

Comment: [ESLint] 'exhaustive-deps' lint rule #14920 this happens

Comment: let me rewrite my answer

Comment: i update my code in question. maybe this can help you

Comment: can you try this answer please

Comment: React Hook React.useCallback has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. terrible situation

Comment: just add dispatch to the array.

Comment: `const updateSearchValue = React.useCallback((str: string) => {
    debounce(() => {
      dispatch(setSearchValue(str));
    }, 150);
  }, [dispatch]);

  const onChangeInput = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
    updateSearchValue(event.target.value); 
  };`

This workes! Thank you!

Comment: glad it worked. following the linter's advice is helpful in these situations